# Using Supertest in Mocha to test Node.js Express API and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, supertest

I am trying to test the REST function of my API, but the PUT test never seems to work. Each time the test runs in mocha, I get the error

> "Uncaught assertion error: expected [] to equal {objectData}"

where `objectData` is the JSON representation of the object I am trying to post (named `couponTwo`).

I have a feeling the problem lies in the `beforeEach` function, as it clears the database before each test, which needs to be done for many other tests to run correctly. Here is the test code:

```
var config = require('../config/config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var should = require('should');
var request = require('supertest');  
var Coupon = require('../models/coupon');
var url = require('../config/config').test.url;

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

beforeEach(function (done) {

  function clearCollections() {
    for (var collection in mongoose.connection.collections) {
      mongoose.connection.collections[collection].remove(function() {});
    }
    return done();
  }

  if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 0) {
    mongoose.connect(config.test.db, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      return clearCollections();
    });
  } else {
    return clearCollections();
  }
});

afterEach(function (done) {
  mongoose.disconnect();
  return done();
});
```

Here is the  that is supposed to test that an object exists in the database after a PUT:

```
describe('#post', function () {
it('should return a coupon object after post', function (done) {
request(url).post('/coupons')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .send(couponTwo)
  
  request(url).get('/coupons').end(function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(res.body);
    res.body.should.eql(couponTwo);
    done();
  })
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the asynchronous nature of request calls. You need to wrap the second request in a callback, so that it will only be executed when the first one is completed and your test object is put into the database.

Also, `.eql(couponTwo)` will fail in your case anyway, because your response is an array containing the object that was put, and you compare it directly to the object. Use `.eql([couponTwo])` if you want to make sure that it is the only element in the array, or just use `.containEql(couponTwo)`.

Try this:

```
request(url).post('/coupons')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
.send(couponTwo)
.end(function () {
  request(url).get('/coupons').end(function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(res.body);
    res.body.should.containEql(couponTwo);
    done();
  });
});
```